# Singularity v3.9.4 Installation - mconfig not inside a git repository and no VERSION file found

Tags: installation, centos7, singularity-container

I'm trying to install Singularity after installing Go. I've confirmed that Go has been installed successfully:

```sh
$ go version
go version go1.17.6 linux/amd64
```

After that, I run the following commands:

```
$ export VERSION=3.9.4
$ wget https://github.com/sylabs/singularity/archive/refs/tags/v${VERSION}.tar.gz
$ tar -xzf v${VERSION}.tar.gz
$ cd singularity-${VERSION}

$ ./mconfig # This is where it fails
E: Not inside a git repository and no VERSION file found. Abort.
```

Comment: This looks basically correct as per https://sylabs.io/guides/3.0/user-guide/installation.html (with some slight alterations). Note that `mconfig` is some sort of custom program or script; anything it does isn't specific to Git or Go unless it actually invokes Git or Go (and then you'd need to specify what it is doing here). It looks like `mconfig` is looking for a file named `VERSION`, that's missing from the release you installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tarball you are downloading is the one generated automatically for a tag, not the release tarball. From the [release page](https://github.com/sylabs/singularity/releases/v3.9.4):

> Source Code
>
> Please use the singularity-ce-3.9.4.tar.gz download below to obtain and install SingularityCE 3.9.4. The GitHub auto-generated 'Source Code' downloads do not include required dependencies etc.

Working snippet using the correct url:

```sh
export VERSION=3.9.4
wget https://github.com/sylabs/singularity/releases/download/v${VERSION}/singularity-ce-${VERSION}.tar.gz && \
    tar xf singularity-ce-${VERSION}.tar.gz && \
    cd singularity-ce-${VERSION} && \
    ./mconfig
```